# Convert time from JSON string with PHP

Tags: php, json, string, date, time

I have an issue with converting time string I get from JSON to another format. Somehow the date is set to minus 24 hours.
Here's object from JSON

```
 [date] => 2011-07-02T00:00:00+02:00
```

I'm using `strtotime()` and `date()`

```
date('l, d F Y', strtotime($day->date));
```

But the output looks like this

```
FRIDAY, 01 JULY 2011
```

Obviously the date in JSON is Second of July. Does anyone have any idea why this happens? Am I missing something important? Will really appreciate any help!

Answer (score 4):

I think you should use [DateTime](http://php.net/datetime). It does not depend on hosts TimeZone. Beside the format is valid ISO8601. So DateTime would have not problem at all.

```
$dt = new DateTime("2011-07-02T00:00:00+02:00");
echo $dt->format("l, d F Y"); 

// Echos Saturday, 02 July 2011
```

http://ideone.com/yPp4d

Comment: Thanks! I fixed it by calling `date_default_timezone_set`

Comment: @JuliaDemchenko Thats a bad practice to alter default time zone that affects whole application

Comment: I understand. In my case the time is bound to an event which takes place in a certain timezone, so there is no need to show time depending on the user timezone.

Comment: If have to parse different timezones for different users, you'll face problem!

Answer (score -1):

PHP doesn't understand an infinite array of time/date strings. What is 'obvious' to a human, is not so obvious to a computer. Without a specific parser for that exact date format, how is the computer language to understand what the `T` in your example is for??

[PHP strtotime formats](http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.formats.date.php) will show you what formats PHP can convert a string from, to a time or date  object.

Even as the date/time is parsing correctly, your `tzcorrection` of +0200 is telling PHP to correct for a timezone difference of GMT + 2 hours, which is likely not your correct timezone offset and thus giving you the error.

Comment: -1 This is the well-known [ISO8601](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) format, which `strotime` definitely understands.